# OpenSimplexNoise higher detail level

Tags: java, perlin-noise, procedural-generation, simplex-noise, simplex-algorithm

I'm new to world generation and the algorithms which are used for them, so I hope someone can give me some usefull explanation or code or both or links to some resources I missed while searching for a solution.

How can I get a higher detail level with OpenSimplexNoise?

I know in some algorithms like PerlinNoise can it be done with frequency
and adding multiply octaves together.
So how can I achieve such a thing with OpenSimplexNoise?

Here is what I've already got:

```
    private static final int WIDTH = 512;
private static final int HEIGHT = 512;
private static final double FEATURE_SIZE = 64;

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException {

    OpenSimplexNoise noise = new OpenSimplexNoise(1233313l);
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
        {
            double value = noise.eval(x / FEATURE_SIZE, y / FEATURE_SIZE);
            int rgb = 0x010101 * (int)((value + 1) * 127.5);
            image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("noise1.bmp"));
}
```

And how can I achieve it to have more flat results for forests etc.?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by 'higher detail level' & 'more flat results'? Please either give numerical &/or image examples of what you're currently getting & what you want instead.

Comment: http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/images/terrainf8p1.jpg
Thats an example image. As you can see there are mountains but also some nice flat terrain with lot of details. I know this can be achieved in PerlinNoise with adding mulitply octaves together and with the frequency, but I don't know how to do this in OpenSimplexNoise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSimplexNoise does not directly provide functionality you've described, so you'll need to provide it yourself. Basically you repeatedly generate a layer of noise & adding it to the final result. More specifically:

- The number of octaves is controlled by the number of times you loop.
- The amplitude of a layer is controlled by multiplying the values of a given layer by some amount.  The amplitude is typically derived from the octave number; the most common example  is to use `1/(2^n)` where `n` is number of the current octave.
- The frequency can be controlled by adjusting your sampling interval. With regard OpenSimplexNoise, you can do this by multiplying your `x  y  z` parameters by some amount. Again, this is typically derived from the octave number & the most common example mutliple is `2^n`.

Tuning the number of octaves, amplitude & frequency values is more of an art than a science & depends highly on your situation. Experiment a bit & research what others have used to find what's right for your project. I get nice results using 6 octaves with the standard amplitude & frequency described above.